# Magento 2 Load REST API cart quote on frontend via URL

Tags: magento2, checkout, quote, shopping-cart, rest-api

I want to load a previous generated quote in magento 2 using REST API. Directly on frontend using custom URL like **"/myurl/cart/index"** that should redirect to **"/checkout/cart"** with the products loaded. That I'm doing in API is the following:

> 1) POST **/rest/V1/guest-carts**

Return something like: **bca5b94b97710599026d73h358e058f7**

> 2) POST **rest/V1/guest-carts/bca5b94b97710599026d73h358e058f7/items**

```
{
  "cartId": "bca5b94b97710599026d73h358e058f7",
  "cart_item": {
    "quote_id": "bca5b94b97710599026d73h358e058f7",
    "sku": "mysku",
    "qty": 1
  }
}
```

the above return the item added. **Then:**

> 3) GET **/rest/V1/guest-carts/bca5b94b97710599026d73h358e058f7**

That return cart object:

```
{
    "id": 21,
    "created_at": "2018-07-30 18:07:14",
    "updated_at": "2018-07-30 18:32:21",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_virtual": false,
    "items": [
        {
            "item_id": 2,
            "sku": "mysku",
            "qty": 1,
            "name": "Test",
            "price": 150,
            "product_type": "simple",
            "quote_id": "5"
        }
    ]
}
```

> 4) Then I've managed to load the quote in my controller with route "/myurl/cart/index" and I can see my quote loaded, something like:

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 21
    [store_id] => 1
    [created_at] => 2018-07-30 18:07:14
    [updated_at] => 2018-07-30 18:32:21
    [converted_at] => 
    [is_active] => 1
    [is_virtual] => 0
    [is_multi_shipping] => 0
    [items_count] => 1
    [items_qty] => 1.0000
    [orig_order_id] => 0
    [store_to_base_rate] => 0.0000
    [store_to_quote_rate] => 0.0000
    [base_currency_code] => USD
    [store_currency_code] => USD
    [quote_currency_code] => USD
    [grand_total] => 150.0000
    [base_grand_total] => 150.0000
    [checkout_method] => 
    [customer_id] => 
    [customer_tax_class_id] => 3
    [customer_group_id] => 0
    [customer_email] => 
    [customer_prefix] => 
    [customer_firstname] => 
    [customer_middlename] => 
    [customer_lastname] => 
    [customer_suffix] => 
    [customer_dob] => 
    [customer_note] => 
    [customer_note_notify] => 1
    [customer_is_guest] => 0
    [remote_ip] => 
    [applied_rule_ids] => 
    [reserved_order_id] => 
    [password_hash] => 
    [coupon_code] => 
    [global_currency_code] => USD
    [base_to_global_rate] => 1.0000
    [base_to_quote_rate] => 1.0000
    [customer_taxvat] => 
    [customer_gender] => 
    [subtotal] => 150.0000
    [base_subtotal] => 150.0000
    [subtotal_with_discount] => 150.0000
    [base_subtotal_with_discount] => 150.0000
    [is_changed] => 1
    [trigger_recollect] => 0
    [ext_shipping_info] => 
    [is_persistent] => 0
    [gift_message_id] => 
)
```

Which is fine, but now I need to redirect to the cart/checkout in frontend with products loaded to display to the **guest** user/customer.. Is that possible without create an order?

Thanks,

Comment: are you loading a phtml and block to do this? If yes you should  do all the business logic in block and pass output to a function like $block->function();  Also you can redirect in phtml.

Comment: Hi @VivekKumar, I'm only using controller to load the quote, I wish to redirect to cart or checkout page from there, with quote loaded in order the customer can be able to finish the checkout process by itself.

Comment: @BrunoSerfe nice post regarding that i can also get the same output but my cart is still empty for guest user any idea regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I've managed to resolve my own inquiry with 3 lines of code from my controller, I hope this help someone else:

```
/* Load quote id */
$quoteId = '21';// this should be loaded from url, I'll make this a TODO
$q = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
/* Load in checkout session as guest */
$this->checkoutSession->setQuoteId($quoteId);
/* Redirect to cart page */
$this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect('/checkout/cart/index')->sendResponse();
```

And that's it, after that I'll be redirected to **"checkout/cart/index"** from **"/myurl/cart/index"** with products loaded from that quote after process that code in **execute()** function.

Comment: I'm glad this question/answer was helpful for other people like you @AdityaShah you're welcome!